# Docked icon for python Tkinter app window on screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, popupwindow, dock

I have created an exe file of a python script. The exe file on running opens a Tkinter window containing some functionality.
I want to have a docked icon which will be present on the screen all the time and when  click it, it should expand to the tkinter window. For eg. just like how the Cisco Jabber docked side pop up app works.
[image: Cisco Jabber side pop up]
[image: Docked window of Jabber]
However I am not able to find a solution for creating a docked app in python. I want that side pop up app to be on the screen all the time.

Could someone please help?

Comment: What did you tried to achieve this so far?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set `overrideredirect` to `True` and the use `.attributes('-topmost', True)` to keep it at top of all the windows.

Here is an example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def expand(event):
    w = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    root.geometry(f"200x50+{(w-200)//2}+0")

def collapse(event):

    w = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    root.geometry(f"200x20+{(w-200)//2}+0")

root = tk.Tk()
collapse(None)
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.attributes('-topmost', True)

button = tk.Button(root, text="x", command=root.destroy)
button.pack(side="left")


button2 = tk.Button(root, text="open Top level", command=tk.Toplevel)
button2.pack(side="left", expand=True, fill="both")
root.bind("<Enter>", expand)
root.bind("<Leave>", collapse)
root.mainloop()
```